# Is there a way to conditionally run rails callbacks only when the model is skipping validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

When I run `model.save(:validate => false)`, I want to run a before_save callback, but only when validate is false, and not when it's true.

I know you can conditionally run callbacks like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :normalize_card_number, if: :paid_with_card?
end
```

but how can you check whether `:validate => false` was passed in?

Comment: You can do it by overwriting the `save` method to parse the args and store the `validate: false` value in a virtual attribute, before checking this attribute in the `before_save` all. But this seems a bit overcomplicated, and might be an X-Y problem. Why do you need to call `validate: false` as part of your code? If it's only in one specific part of the application, maybe you could explicitly run the callback logic from there (instead of hooking it into the model lifecycle).

Answer (score 1):

Using @maxpleaner's comment, you can achieve that by doing something like,

```
# overwriting the save method to parse the args and store the validate: false value in a virtual attribute (@my_options below)
module ActiveRecord
  module Validations
    def save(**options)
      @my_options = options # => {:validate=>false} in your case
      perform_validations(options) ? super : false
    end
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :normalize_card_number, if: :paid_with_card?
  
  private

  def normalize_card_number
   # using the virtual attribute to solve your problem
    return unless my_options[:validate].eql?(false)
    # Your logic when :validate => false is not passed
  end
end
```